# I am stuck with a scenario regarding extracting the country code

Tags: java

While uploading the phone number, some add with country code like `+91` or `91`, `+44` or `44`. In this scenario how can I remove the country code.

While fetching the numbers, it will be like

```
[+91 xxxxxxxxxx, 91 xxxxxxxxxx, +44 xxxxxxxxxx, 44 xxxxxxxxxx]
```

Comment: This is an extremely complex problem, because you've got to allow for a county code of between 1-3 digits, plus a numeric range which is not consistent.  If you get +1123456789 then, you're screwed :/, if the country code is delimited with a space or other character, then you'd have more luck

Comment: country code and number contain space, right? if yes then split the string and take the second index.

Comment: IMO you will have come up with variations in data and make some assumptions. Based on those you can create regex to format phone numbers

Comment: you can treat it separately, for instance giving the user the chance to select their country, and just have a numeric field for the rest of phone number

Comment: If all phone numbers *will* have a country code and *will* have space after the country code, and your question doesn't say otherwise, then you're simply asking how to remove the text up to and including the first space. Is that really your question?

Comment: Google has a library called libphonenumber just for parsing phone numbers, I cannot guarantee how anonymous the check is as I have not gone through the source yet. here is the current GitHub link : https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the country codes on [countrycode.org](https://countrycode.org/), you be able to build a regex to recognize valid country codes:

```regex
^\+?(?:[17]|2[07]|3[0-469]|4[013-9]|5[1-8]|6[0-6]|8[1246]|9[0-58]|(?:2[^07]|3[^0-469]|4[^013-9]|5[^1-8]|6[^0-6]|8[^1246]|9[^0-58])[0-9])[ ]
```

Comment: @odonol Yes use regex with partial selection from input. That can be done with parenthesis around part which you wants to select

Answer (score 0):

From your question,

1. Assuming that few phone numbers will be with country code and few will be only phone numbers.
2. And also assuming that if someone adds phone number with country code, they give space between country code and phone number.

   ```
   List<String> numbersWithoutCode = new LinkedList<String>();
   String phoneNums[] = { "+91 1010101010", "1111111111" };
   for (String phNum : phoneNums) {
       String nums[] = phNum.split(" ");
       if (nums.length > 1) {
           numbersWithoutCode.add(nums[1]);
       } else {
           numbersWithoutCode.add(phNum);
       }
   }

   System.out.println(numbersWithoutCode);
   ```